# I want to encrypt data using ANSi code but data remains unchanged after encryption

Tags: c, encryption

I want to use ANSI code to encrypt my data in a structure String. But to my surprice, data remains unchanged after the operation.
String is a struct including a string and the size of the string defined by myself,as well as key.
Here's my code:

```
String cipher(String textMsg,  String key, Boolean isEncrypt){

    int i,j;
    String *newStr = (String *)malloc(sizeof(textMsg));
    *newStr = textMsg;
    if(DEBUG)
        printf( "***%20s ***\n", __FUNCTION__ );
    if(isEncrypt == FALSE){
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i < textMsg.size; i ++, j ++){
            newStr->addr[i] += key.addr[j%key.size];
            newStr->addr[i] = rotate_fit(newStr->addr[i], 0, 127);
        //the rotate function is shown below
        }

    }
    else{
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i < textMsg.size; i ++, j ++){
            newStr->addr[i] -= key.addr[j%key.size];
            newStr->addr[i] = rotate_fit(newStr->addr[i], 0, 127);
        }
    }
    return *newStr;
}

int rotate_fit(int x, int min, int max){
    if(x >= min && x <= max)
        return x;
    if(x < min)
        return max+x+1;
    if(x > max)
        return x-max-1;
    return 0;
}
```

So could someone tell me what's wrong with my code or my method of encryption? Many thanks!

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of `rotate_fit`.

Comment: ANSI-code? Which ANSI code?

Comment: your code is ignoring the return value from `rotate_fit`

Comment: I've corrected it. Actually, I use the rotate_fit function for fear that the encrypted char will surpass the limit of the ANSI code. @FedericoklezCulloca@Chris Turner

Comment: I don't know its name clearly. It has a range of decimal integers from 0 to 127 to represent different chars.@Olaf

Comment: Your string handling looks very suspect.  If String is a struct that you made, then mallocing a new one and copying the contents will not actually copy the string.  It will just copy the pointer to the old string.  If I were you I wouldn't invent clever ways to do strings in C.  Either use C++, or give up and pass simple buffers and buffer sizes to all of your functions.

Comment: And be aware that common C string handling is subject to all kinds of buffer overruns. So your encryption / decryption functions may become a vulnerability rather than an asset. But that's C I suppose. Use static analysis if available.